# Extending an Inner class into a Nested class?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, inner-classes

I was learning about Nested and Inner classes and this led me to think whether it is possible to extend an Inner class to be a Nested class or not. For example.

```
public class Outer{

    public class Inner{
        // notice the lack of static keyword
    }
}


public class ExtendedOuter extends Outer{

    public static class ExtendedInner extends Inner{
        // notice the static keyword
    }
}
```

I did try to compile the code above and I couldn't, but the compile time error I received made me believe that there may be a work around. I can however extend a Nested class to be an Inner class.

This is the compile time error I received.

> no enclosing instance of type Outer is in scope

Comment: A `static` class cannot extend a non-`static` inner class.

Comment: `Inner` should be static, otherwise it has to be bound to an instance of `Outer`, just as the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can extend the inner class. You just have to provide an instance of `Outer` that the class will be bound to. To do so, you have to explicitly call the `super` constructor with the instance.

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner{
        // notice the lack of static keyword
    }
}

public class ExtendedOuter extends Outer {

    private static Outer outer = new ExtendedOuter(); // or any other instance

    public static class ExtendedInner extends Inner {
        public ExtendedInner() {
            outer.super(); // this call is explicitly required
        }
    }

}
```

This also works if you have a nested class that extends another nested class from a different enclosing class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for some reason this is the kind of work around I was suspecting there may be. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An inner class has a reference to the outer class.  You cannot remove it in a subclass.  This would be like removing a field in a sub-class.

Comment: I see, in other words there is no work around and an Inner class cannot be extended to be a Nested class right ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: An *inner* class has a reference to the outer class. You can remove it by making the nested class static instead of inner.

Comment: @twimB because it doesn't make sense, no.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense. An inner class is already a nested class, and so is any other class defined inside another one. Evidently you don't know what these words mean:

- nested class: a class declared inside another one
- inner class: a nested class that isn't declared 'static'.

Note that 'static nested' and 'inner' are mutually exclusive. Note also that an inner class can extend a static nested class, but not vice versa.

What your code is actually trying to do is extend the inner class as a *static* class, which is what causes the error. Not because the extending class is nested.

Comment: Well to me the question makes a lot of sense, since that purpose is simply to know if it is possible or not I haven't come to the need to apply the above in my code. It is the compile time error that made me think there may be a way to do so

Comment: If you've understood my answer, you should also understand that the question doesn't make sense as asked. Ergo you haven't understood my answer. I suggest that you read it again. I've told you what is and isn't possible, but you don't need to even ask whether something that is already logically entailed is 'possible'. You clearly have a misunderstanding of the terminology. What you are *actually* attempting in your code isn't extension to be nested, it is extension to be static. It isn't the same thing.

Comment: Maybe it is me not getting what you try to explain in your answer. However Peter Lawrey's answer made it clear to me. Maybe it would have made more sense to you if I asked the question slightly different like, "Is it possible to extend a non-static nested class to be a static nested class". I do know that a non-static nested class must bind to an instance of the enclosing class. thanks for your answer.